Opening file with fstream
I have written a class for handling text files and it looks like this.
#include <fstream>
#include "String.h"

class TextFile
{
    std::fstream stream;

public:
    TextFile(const String& filename)
    {
        stream.open(filename.data(), std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    std::cout << "File opened " << filename.data() << " " << stream.is_open() << std::endl;
    }

    ~TextFile()
    {
        close();
    }

    template <typename T>
    TextFile& operator<<(const T& data)
    {
        stream << data;
        return *this;
    }

    TextFile& operator<<(const String& s)
    {
        stream << s.data();
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    TextFile& operator>>(T& data)
    {
        stream >> data;
        return *this;
    }

    void close() 
    {
        if (stream.is_open()) 
            stream.close();
    }
};

I intentionally used fstream and not ifstream or ofstream, because at the time of opening the file, I do not yet know whether I will write to it or read from it. I would then use the TextFile in one of two ways:
TextFile file("somefile.txt")
file << "hello world";
file.close();

TextFile file("somefile.txt")
file >> someString;
file.close();

My issue with this is that it won't open the file, unless it already exists. It only does that if I add std::ios::app to the arguments, but I don't want to append. I want the file to be created, if it doesn't exist, and overwrite its contents if it already does. How do I do this right?

What is your actual assignment or exercise? Why do you need to create this wrapper around streams? Why do you need to create your own String class?

This might be relevant: How is std::fstream with both in and out supposed to work?.

As for your problem, the table in this reference could be helpful.

And without String.h and a main, this isn't a [mcve].

'how do I do this right'. Perhaps by checking if the file exists before you try to open it, and then chosing the appropriate options depending on whether it does exist or not. Your requiremants are a little unusual so it's perhaps not surprising that there isn't a simple way to do what you want.

I'm creating infrastructure similar to Qt for making it easier to work with C++. I find the interface to read and write a text file as described in my post convenient to work with. That is also why I have my own String class, which is simply prettier and more convenient than std::string and supports commonly used functions like split and trim.

Another option would be to postpone opening the file until the first time operator<< or operator>> is called. At that point, you'd know whether to use in|out or in|out|trunc

Thank you for the great suggestions and references. I went with the "checking if the file exists" approach and it works perfectly. Postponing the opening of the file sounds like a good approach as well.
